# android notifyDataSetChanged doesn't work

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I bind an adapter to ListView in onCreate(), every time when activity is in onResume(), I will update the appinfos data in the adapter, and called notifyDataSetChanged in adapter setdata() method. But I don't get The ListView refreshed even the data changed in my adapter. I can't figure out what's the problem, could you help me out? thanks

Here is my activity using adapter and set data to listview.

```
List<AppInfo> appinfos = new ArrayList<AppInfo>();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getAppInfos();
    adapter=new UnistallListAdapter(this,appinfos);
    applistView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    getAppInfos();
    adapter.setdata(appinfos);
    super.onResume();
}


private List<AppInfo> getAppInfos() {
    appinfos.clear();
            //do some thing, new an item; and add into appinfos object
            //the appinfos data often changed here, 
            // as I uninstall app before activity called onResume().
           ......       
          appinfos.add(info);
            .....
    return appinfos;
}
```

Below is the main code of my UnistallListAdapter, and how to change its data.

```
private List<AppInfo>infos;
    public UnistallListAdapter(Context c,List<AppInfo>info)
{
    mContext = c;
    inflate=LayoutInflater.from(c);
    infos=info;
}

   @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return infos.get(position);
    }

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return infos.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ViewHold holder = null;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        convertView=inflate.inflate(R.layout.uninstall_item, null);
        holder=new ViewHold();
        holder.name=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.icon=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        holder.ai = infos.get(position);;
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder=(ViewHold)convertView.getTag();
    }

    AppInfo ai = holder.ai;
    holder.name.setText(ai.mAppLabel);
    holder.icon.setImageDrawable(ai.mIcon);

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHold
{
    AppInfo ai;
    ImageView icon;
    TextView name;
}
public void setdata(List<AppInfo> dataList) {
    infos = dataList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

please give me some help, and any hint about reason is welcome. I would be highly appreciate your help.

Comment: Please post some more of your adapter code.

Comment: I think this is enough if we focused on the data changed. which part do you want to see? the other part code is the same flow as implementing getView, getItem, getCount, etc...

Comment: why do you call update stuff in onResume()?

Comment: @pskink, I called update stuff in onResume()->setdata()->notifyDataSetChanged(update stuff method), did i catch your mean？

Comment: @gladman i am asking why onResume at all

Comment: I'd start by checking `getCount()` in the adapter but there are other overrides there that can make the refresh "not work".

Comment: Check the method 'getAppInfos()' is adds same kind of data or not, I think retuned or appinfos's list data is always add similar data. Then there is no change at all and no change in list view.  Note:- 'onResume()' should call after 'onCreate()' exection at the start up of Activity.

Comment: @laalto I updated the adapter code, the appinfos data is referenced global, and it has been changed in getAppInfos(), and set to adapter by setdata()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
holder.ai = infos.get(position);
```

You're storing an object reference in the view holder and never update that.

View holder is not supposed to contain references to data objects, just the views. Use `getItem(position)` to get an up-to-date data object each time in `getView()`.

Comment: Thanks @laalto, I think you are right. I have tried what you said, it refresh successfully. I am very grateful of your help.

Answer (score 4):

Change this:

```
public void setdata(List<AppInfo> dataList) {
  infos = dataList;
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

to

```
public void setdata(List<AppInfo> dataList) {
  infos.clear();
  infos.putAll(dataList);
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

reset the data contained in the list NOT its reference.

Comment: yes, I have tried your answer, putAll() replaced with addAll(), right? But The result is I got the blank listview on the screen. And I add debug log, I log out dataList.size() and infos.size(), all count is zero. But in onResume(), the appinfos size is 13. D/appsviewer(18022): onResume 13
D/appsviewer(18022): setdata count 0 dataList 0

Answer (score 0):

In the onResume method you are making a call to getAppInfos();. However you are not assigning it your ArrayList appinfos. Hence it is not getting updated and passing the same list to setdata() method.

Do,

```
this.appinfos = getAppInfos();
adapter.setdata(appinfos);
super.onResume();
```

OR

```
adapter.setdata(getAppInfos());
super.onResume();
```

Comment: I understood the code that it's a member variable and its reference has been passed to the adapter. So modifying the list modifies the same list that has been passed to the adapter.

Comment: This is not true, the items are added to the ArrayList member inside the getAppInfos() method.

Answer (score 0):

add applistView.setAdapter(adapter); in the onResume after adapter.setdata(appinfos);